# JavaScript - Event listener with window.matchMedia not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I've panned through countless solutions to this problem and none of them have fixed my issue. I very simply have a navigation bar, which, when on a mobile browser, disappears and becomes replaced with a button, whose function is to show and hide the navigation bar.

Now, I want my listener to, when the window is shrunk, show the button and hide the navigation bar. When the window is expanded, the button should be hidden and the navigation bar should be shown. The button is working as it should be, since the media query doesn't affect it. My listener appears to not run at all, except when the page is reloaded.

My script is contained inside of a PHP header which is included at the beginning of all my pages. Here's what I've got:

**Media Query Listener** (contained in header.php code)

```
// ... navbar code, opening script tag, yadda yadda
function mediaQueryCheck(inputQuery) {
    var content = document.getElementById("navigation");
    if (inputQuery.matches) {
        // it matches
        content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        // it does not match
        content.style.display = "block";
    }
}
var mobileQuery = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 638px)");
mediaQueryCheck(mobileQuery);
mobileQuery.addEventListener(mediaQueryCheck);
// closing script tag
```

The element `#navigation` is a div element containing the navigation bar. I will provide any other relevant code, if necessary.

Comment: The interface returned by matchMedia only calls it's listener when the state of the media query changes. It's unclear what you mean by window "shrunk" or "expanded" on a mobile browser. The screen width isn't going to change as you typically can't resize a mobile browser window.

Comment: you need to use `addListener` instead of  `addEventListener`

Comment: I may be missing some detail in your description of what you are trying to accomplish but why aren't you just using [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this?

Comment: @benvc CSS media queries would solve the problem as described but OP may have other reasons to do it in JS

Comment: Thank you @ZohirSalak - that did the trick!

Comment: I am using CSS media queries, although I need to use JS in conjunction with these media queries. The media queries are overriden by the usage of the button, thus if I pressed the button to hide my navbar in the mobile layout, it will remain hidden even when I reexpand the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `addListener` instead of `addEventListener` fixed the problem.

Comment: Specifically, I'm assuming, [`MediaQueryList.addListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener).

Comment: instead of `addListener` you have to use `addEventListener` whith **change** event, because of the deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

for whoever needs another solution:
**you may use this function:**

```
function getWidth() {
  var maxWidth = Math.max(
        document.body.scrollWidth,
        document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
        document.body.offsetWidth,
        document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
        document.documentElement.clientWidth
   );
   console.log(maxWidth); // for testing only
   if(maxWidth === 776){
       //do sth
   }
   if(maxWidth === 992){
       //do sth
   }
   return maxWidth;
}
window.addEventListener("resize", getWidth);
```

**now you have the width of the screen all the time**
this is just another way of doing things... you may wanna use whatever serves your purpose.

Comment: This is less performant as it triggers on every resize event and recalculates the layout for each call to clientWidth

Answer (score 0):

The `addListener` callback is deprecated and the `addEventListener` is recommended in the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener):

```
const mobileQuery = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 638px)");
mobileQuery.addEventListener("change", mediaQueryCheck);
// or explicit
// mobileQuery.addEventListener("change", e => mediaQueryCheck(e));
```

The relevant event is the "change" event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/change_event

Answer (score -1):

You have to check it every time, when window is resized.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  mediaQueryCheck(mobileQuery);
});
```

Comment: Untrue and irrelevant. The object returned by matchMedia offers an event handler, and mobile browser windows aren't likely to be resized, which I'm guessing is the problem the OP has anyways.